# DevOps build is loading an old .dll file for a project that no longer exists

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, devops, tfsbuild

Our DevOps build keeps failing on some unit tests. Digging through the logs, it looks like there is an old .dll file for a Unit Test project the no longer exists. All tests from this old project have been moved to other projects.

[image]

the xxx.APITests project is the one that no longer exists.  But I don't know why or how the .dll for that project is still being loaded by DevOps. How do I get rid of it?

**EDIT:**

We are using VSTS

Comment: Did you do a clean before your build? If that .dll still exists in the release folder it will happily be loaded and has its tests run.

Comment: Yes. I always clean :)

Comment: And it's not MY build that is in question. It's the build on the DevOps server.

Comment: That doesn't matter. The clean target is not run by default and the build target has no clue if already present files needs to be removed.

Comment: Search the project and nuget files for references to that assembly's name.  It must be getting referenced somewhere.

Comment: @Amy, on my localhost, no trace of the project exists. Anywhere. And I have also gotten the latest, specific version w/ overwrite. Still no trace of it.

Comment: @rene, see comment above to Amy.

Comment: Right, I understood.  But I'm telling ya, there is no such thing. At least not that I can find. I have searched all files (using Windows search) and I have searched IN all files (using NotePad++) for "APITests" and i get nothing.

Comment: You can exclude this tests dll from running using `vstest.console` command, if don't find the reason, why it's present

Comment: Does your build server use a completely fresh directly before each build?  As in, create build dir, checkout files, do build, do things with build artifacts, then erase the build dir when done?  Maybe the DLL is left over from an older build and was simply never cleaned up.

Comment: @Amy, I'm not sure. My knowledge of DevOps is limited. How would I check?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski, ok I will look into that. Not sure how to do it, but I'll google it

Comment: I mean, the way I see this, there's two possibilities:  (1) the DLL is being pulled into each build.  I think this has been ruled out.  (2) the DLL is left-over from previous builds and was simply never cleaned up.  If this is it, then removing the file from the build server should resolve this.  If not, then you're back to #1.

Comment: @Amy, I'm right with you. 1) I can't imagine how. 2) I don't know how!! (I should have said: we are using VSTS)

Comment: @Amy... the weird thing is... I can't find the actuall .dll in the file browser in VSTS.

Comment: @CaseyCrookston [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/vstest-console-options?view=vs-2019) you are. You can remove filename from command arguments or use a TestCaseFilter

Comment: In your Azure DevOps build you should be able to configure the Clean options in the `Get Sources` pane, you'll want to set the Clean option in the `Get Sources` pane to true and add a variable called `Build.Clean` whose value is set to `All`. This will clean **before** each build, to clean **after** each build then you'll need a `Delete Folder` task at the end of your definition.

Comment: what you could do is add to the BeforeBuild target a [`<Delete >`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/delete-task?view=vs-2019) task and use an [`ItemGroup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/item-element-msbuild?view=vs-2019) to find that stale APItests.dll. In theory you omly need to run that once.

Comment: Another option for cleaning is to update your MSBuild/Visual Studio/dotnet task in Azure DevOps to run a clean before each build, so the bin & obj folders are deleted from each project.This is a 'soft' clean in that it doesn't delete the build checkout directory.

Comment: @ColinM, ok, this sounds like the solution I am looking for. I don't have admin privileges on VSTS, but I will submit a request to make this happen.

Comment: You should only require the `Build Administrators` group permission as opposed to the wider administration permission.Should the build update not fix the issue then you could perform a global find with VS Code or Notepad++ and look for APITests.dll at the root of the solution directory, where the file filter is `*.*` for all files. Happy hunting.

Comment: @CaseyCrookston you can remote login to build server (which your VSTS agent is connected to) and navigate to the folder and manually delete the dll in question.

Comment: @sam not if he's running the build on an Azure DevOps server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are using [Self-hosted build agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser) working with DevOps, you can check the agent pool and agent your build using in the pipeline, and login the machine where the agent runs, delete the .dll files.

If your issue persists, share your pipeline definition.

Comment: Have you checked machine where agent runs? Do the .dll files exist?